# Processing all data in a for loop instead of only one element

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

I wrote some code in order to scrape some data from a website. When I run the code manually I can get all the information for all the shoes, but when I run my script it only gives me one result for each variable.

What can I change to get all the results I want?

For example, when I run the following, I only get one result for `marque` and one for `modele`, but when i do it in my terminal I can see that `vignette` contains multiple values.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r=requests.get('https://www.sarenza.com/store/product/gender-type/list/view?gender=1&type=76&index=0&count=99')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
vignette=soup.find_all('li',class_='vignette')

for i in range(len(vignette)):
    marque=vignette[i].contents[3].text
    modele=vignette[i].contents[5].contents[3].text
```

Comment: You should make your question clearer. What exactly goes wrong? Reduce the code to the bare minimum and provide a working example. Also, what have you tried to solve the issue?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I reduce the code to the minimum and explained a little more

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is a link with some more details on how to ask a question so that it is possible to help. Can you add what you type in terminal and what the output is that you wish to get and what the output is that you get from your script?

Answer (score 1):

You're updating your `marque` and `modele` variables overwriting their previous value on each iteration of the loop. At the end of the loop, they will only contain the last values that were assigned to them.

If you want to extract all the values, you need to use two lists, and append values to them like this:

```
marques = []
modeles = []
for i in range(len(vignette)):
    marques.append(vignette[i].contents[3].text)
    modeles.append(vignette[i].contents[5].contents[3].text)
```

Or, in a more Pythonic way:

```
marques = list(v.contents[3].text for v in vignette)
modeles = list(v.contents[5].contents[3].text for v in vignette)
```

Now you'll have all the values you need, and you can process them or print them out, like this:

```
for marque, modele in zip(marques, modeles):
    print('Marque:', marque, 'Modèle:', modele)
```